# Codeigniter count using month?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

The scenario is I am the admin and I have a session to make, the session table consists of a session_id, coach_name, date(format Y-m-d).
Now I want to count the total activity of the coach every "MONTH".
So my point is how will I get this kind of output in a SQL query.

The desired output is the amount of activity per month, per coach.

```
Name        | No. of session this month
Coach_name1 =   13
Coach_name2 =   5
```

This is my current query that gives me the coach name but I don't know how to get for each MONTH

```
public function getAll(){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT coach_name FROM sessions);
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query to get the result.
Use mysql MONTH() to get Month number from date and group by it. You will get all month wise data.

```
SELECT coach_name,
       Count(*) AS activities
FROM   sessions
WHERE  Month(date) = 8 //for specfic month 
GROUP  BY coach_name, Month(date) // for all months
```

Use this query to dynamincally get current month based on system date

```
SELECT coach_name,
       Count(*) AS activities
FROM   sessions
WHERE  Month(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE()) //for selecting current month.
GROUP  BY coach_name
```

Comment: how do i use no specific month? like its real time, for the next sept and the next coming month

Comment: Remove where claue from it and only use Group By or you can use current month in where clause. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL's [MONTH()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) in your query. So basically if all your data is in your sessions table try the following in your query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`name`),COUNT(`name`) AS `activity` FROM `session` 
WHERE MONTH(`date`)=8 GROUP BY `name`;
```

Check in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e1fbf/7)

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare query like below:

```
select 
       coach_name, 
       month(your_date_field), 
       count(1) 
from 
       your_table 
where 
      month(your_date_field) = 8
group by 
       coach_name, month(your_date_field)
```

Which would return records like below,

```
| coach_name    | month(your_date_field) | count(1)   |
+---------------+------------------------+------------+
| Coach_name1   |                    8   |        x   |
| Coach_name2   |                    8   |        x   |
| Coach_name3   |                    8   |        x   |
+---------------+------------------------+------------+
```

**In codeigniter**

```
$this->db->select("coach_name, month(your_date_field) as month_number,count(1) as counts");
$this->db->where('month(your_date_field)',8);
$this->db->group_by('coach_name,MONTH(your_date_field)');
$query = $this->db->get('your_table');

// results
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
        // do this to see array
        print_r($row);

        // to access individual fields
        echo $row['coach_name']; 
        echo $row['month_number'];
        echo $row['counts'];
}
```

Comment: @Faith: you have to loop through query results, to start see here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: i looped,  <?php echo $sessionlist->'HERE" ?> idk what to put

Comment: @Faith: Glad to know it worked out, [you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)